# ASP.Net multiple textbox controllers for a table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2013

I am making a web application and have a webform connected to an access database table. For one of my queries I have a table with supplier info and I need to filter the results by name, city, and type.

I used the query builder to have the parameters input by the user through 3 textboxes (one for each parameter). When I run the query in the query builder the results come up fine, but when I run it through a browser it fails (the form shows up fine, but it's not taking the input parameters in the textbox to populate the table). I made sure I linked the parameters to the texbox control through the wizard.

I've built forms with a single input parameter controlled with a single textbox and those have worked just fine, but when I used multiple parameters and textboxes it doesn't work in the browser.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using asp:AccessDataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you  bind control with parameter.

```
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter  Name="Comments" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLastName" Name="Title" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

You can pass parameters runtime as below.

```
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>

 protected void AccessDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFirstName.Text.Length > 0 && txtLastName.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["parameter1"].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
            e.Command.Parameters["parameter2"].Value = txtLastName.Text;
        }
    }
```